# How to adjust overlays and base layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: mapserver, openlayers-2, mapfile

I have a mapfile

```
MAP
  NAME "MapChiTieuDau"
  EXTENT         779275 2222000 788430  2233835  
  SIZE           800 800
  UNITS          dd
  STATUS         ON
  IMAGETYPE      png
  SHAPEPATH      "/ms4w/apps/openlayers-3.8.2/DuLieuBachLongVy/Maps"
  IMAGECOLOR     190 232 255
  FONTSET        "/ms4w/apps/tutorial/fonts/fonts.list"

  WEB
   IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/"
   IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
   METADATA
      "wms_title" "WMS Demo Server"
      "wms_onlineresource" "/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/Test/wms/BD_ChiTietDau.map"    
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
   END #end METADATA
  END #end web
  PROJECTION
    "init=EPSG:4326"
  END

  SYMBOL
     NAME "circlef"
     TYPE ellipse
     FILLED true
     POINTS
       10 10
     END # POINTS
  END # SYMBOL

  LAYER 
    NAME         "binh_do_15"
    DATA         binh_do_15
    STATUS       ON
    TYPE         LINE
    CLASSITEM    "SOURCE"
    LABELITEM    "SOURCE"
    DEBUG on
    PROJECTION
        "init=EPSG:4326"
    END
    METADATA
        "wms_title" "binh_do_15"
    END
    CLASS
      NAME       "binh_do_15"
      STYLE
        COLOR    174 213 252
      END
      LABEL
        COLOR 183 68 85
        TYPE TRUETYPE
        FONT arial
        SIZE 12
        ANTIALIAS TRUE
        POSITION CL
        PARTIALS FALSE
        MINDISTANCE 300
        BUFFER 4
        STYLE    # since to version 6
          GEOMTRANSFORM 'labelpoly'
          OFFSET 2 2
        END # STYLE      
      END # end of label
    END
  END 

LAYER
  NAME "chitieu_mt"
  TYPE POINT    
  DUMP true 

  PROJECTION
    "init=EPSG:4326"
  END
  METADATA
    "wms_title" "chitieu_mt"
  END
  DEBUG on
  STATUS on
   DATA chitieu_mt


  CLASSITEM    "Dau"
  LABELITEM    "Dau"
  CLASS
    Name "chitieu_mt"
    STYLE
      SYMBOL "circlef"
      SIZE 16
      COLOR 212 3 255
    END
    TEXT (tostring([Dau],"%.2f"))
    END # end of CLASS
  END # end of LAYER
END
```

and JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map, layer;
var infoControls;
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'); 
var ll, popupClass, popupContentHTML;

function init(){

    format = 'image/png';
     var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(779275, 2222000,788430, 2233835);

     map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        controls:[
           new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
           new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
           new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
           new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
           new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
           new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
           new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
           new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
           new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
        ],
         numZoomLevels:7,
        maxExtent : bounds
     });
    var bdhw = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'MapChiTieuDau','/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/Test/wms/BD_ChiTietDau.map',
            {
                layers: 'chitieu_mt',
                srs: 'EPSG:32628',
                transparent: true,
                format:  format// 'image/gif'
            },  {
                isBaseLayer: true,
                 reproject: true
                 });
    var bdhw2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'MapChiTieuDau2','/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/Test/wms/BD_ChiTietDau.map',
            {
                layers: 'binh_do_15',
                srs: 'EPSG:32628',
                transparent: true,
                format:  format//'image/gif'
            },  {
                isBaseLayer: false,
                 reproject: true
                 });
        map.addLayers([bdhw,bdhw2]);
        map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

        var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");

        var product= <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
             for( var i=0;i<product.length;i++ ) {
                var aboutMarker="<table border='3'><tr><td rowspan='4'><img src='img/hb2-7494d.gif' height='100px' alt='Sakura'/></td></tr><tr><td> Longitude: "+product[i][0]+"</td></tr><tr><td> Latitude: "+product[i][1]+"</td></tr><tr><td> Thông tin dầu: "+product[i][2]+"</td></tr></table>";

                var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(product[i][0],product[i][1]).transform(fromProjection,map.getProjectionObject()),
                        {description:aboutMarker} ,
                        {externalGraphic:'img/marker.png',graphicHeight:25,graphicWidth:21,graphicXOffset:-12,graphicYOffset:-25}
                    );
                vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
             }
             map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
            var controls = {
              selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
            };

            map.addControl(controls['selector']);
            controls['selector'].activate();

   function createPopup(feature) {
  feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
      feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
      null,
      '<div class="markerContent">'+feature.attributes.description+'</div>',
      null,
      true,
      function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
  );
  //feature.popup.closeOnMove = true;
  map.addPopup(feature.popup);
}

function destroyPopup(feature) {
  feature.popup.destroy();
  feature.popup = null;
}
}

</script>
```

I want to show all overlays and base Llayers like a example in dev.Openlayers.org, this is: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html

All layers overlapping. it only shows one that bdhw or bdhw2. How do I have to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I have used "singleTile: true". It like:

```
 var bdhw = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'MapChiTieuDau','/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/Test/wms/BD_ChiTietDau.map',
            {
                layers: 'chitieu_mt',
                srs: 'EPSG:4326',
                transparent: true,
                format:  format// 'image/gif'
            },  {
                isBaseLayer: false,
                 singleTile: true
                 });
```

My problem has fixed success!